# Issue with unwrappind Edit mode to Object mode

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image: uv mapping]
When in edit mode (right) the texture is, say, almost ok. When I press tab to object mode the texturing changes unsepectedly into a completely messy one (left). What can it be? I used uv unwrapping / smart uv project and last cube projection, but with no results.

Comment: please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sorry, what do you mean, why sould i upload? thanks

Comment: so that we understand where is the mistake?

Comment: a blend file would help

Comment: I am uploading it. Actually is my first attempt at an archiviz image. Therefore It might be full or errors or inaccuracy.

Comment: stab in the dark, could it be because of a modifier that isn't visible in edit mode?